# Create an app to display an existing website using xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I would like to create an app to display a website in Android mobiles. I am been looking how to do it and I found Xamarin that uses C#. Somebody know any tutorial or web to learn how to do it?

Comment: First result for 
xamarin android get started  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a webview inside an app which can easily be done using both the flavors of Xamarin and there are tutorials and samples available for both:

1. **Using Xamarin.Forms**

Tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

Github Sample: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithWebview

2. **Using Xamarin.Native**

Tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/web_view/